# Was Gandalf omniscient?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, gandalf

Could Gandalf predict future events? Throughout the legendarium, he seems to come up with prophecies which come true, but is this just lucky guessing/wisdom or genuine omniscience? If it is indeed omniscience is it complete omniscience (as in does he know for sure) or just a sort of 'feeling' that something may happen?

He accurately predicts "Gollum may have a part to play yet" amongst others I can't currently recall.

Comment: @Mithrandir Gandalf! You're late!

Comment: Getting killed was a pretty good sign of a lack of omniscience.

Comment: @Valorum not necessarily. according to the Bible, Jesus is God and God is omniscient, and Jesus knew he had to die. Maybe Gandalf knew he had to die to save the others and become stronger? This of course is only a possibility. But what is the known extent of his future telling?

Comment: Your question is answered by the accepted answer linked above, an example includes: *Gandalf is certainly very wise, but he is definitely not "all knowing". No one in Tolkien's work, aside from Eru Ilúvatar, is all knowing.*

Comment: @Charlie Jesus is not omniscient. But that question belongs on Christianity SE.